# Why Parameter Stops Function When Added

Tags: javascript, html, fadein

I have a code which I am trying to execute using a parameter in the function, i.e -

```
function startFadeEffect(elem){ };
```

I have made the elem equal to a variable b in the global scope, where b is an array of images. Meaning -

```
var elem = b[imgNumb];
```

imgNumb is a variable which is globally "0" and inside a function is defined as

```
imgNumb = imgNumb + count;
```

Now, my current code "without" the parameter works perfect -

```
function startFadeEffect(){
    var opacSetting = noOpac / 10;
    b[imgNumb].style.opacity = opacSetting; 
    b[imgNumb].style.display = "block";
    noOpac++;
    if(noOpac < 0){
        opacSetting = 0;    
    }
    if(opacSetting == 1){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        b[imgNumb].style.opacity = 1;
        noOpac = 0;
        return false;
    }
    var timer = setTimeout(startFadeEffect, 75);
}
```

However, when I use the parameter like this it does not work for me :(

```
function startFadeEffect(elem){
    var opacSetting = noOpac / 10;
    elem.style.opacity = opacSetting;   
    elem.style.display = "block";
    noOpac++;
    if(noOpac < 0){
        opacSetting = 0;    
    }
    if(opacSetting == 1){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        elem.style.opacity = 1;
        noOpac = 0;
        return false;
    }
    var timer = setTimeout(startFadeEffect(elem), 75);
}
```

***Please note I have already defined the elem variable in the global scope of the file. Also, I am only looking for a JS solution no library like JQuery! Thanks***

Comment: And how are you calling the function...? And what does "doesn't work" mean? Any errors? Have you checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is incorrect:

```
setTimeout(startFadeEffect(elem), 75);
```

It should be:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    startFadeEffect(elem);
}, 75);
```

---

`setTimeout` expects a function as it's first argument. `startFadeEffect(elem)` is executed immediately (and doesn't return a function). So what happens is that `startFadeEffect` calls itself recursively until `opacSetting == 1` which breaks the recursion.

Comment: I'd use `startFadeEffect.bind(null, elem)` instead of an anonymous function wrapper, but yeah, same difference...

Comment: That's up to personal preference I suppose. Since we don't have a clear `thisArg` target it feels a bit out of place to use `bind`.

Comment: Okay, thanks it works but now my var elem = b[imgNumb]; does not work outside the function any ideas why??

Comment: var elem = b[imgNumb-1]; when I put it in the global space it does not work. But, when I put it inside the function let's say startFadeEffect(elem); it works!